# Java URLDecode fails while PHP urldecode partially decodes

Tags: java

Here is a malformed URL `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2`.

With PHP

```
var_dump(urldecode("http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2"));
```

I get

```
string(20) "http://example.com%2"
```

However, when using Java

```
URLDecoder.decode("http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
```

This is a simplified URL to showcase my example. How can I still parse as much of the URL as possible in Java, even if it is malformed? Basically, return what **PHP** is returning.

Answer (score 0):

What is the natural URL?
I mean, at the end, there is 2%, what is the natural meanning of http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2 ?
Is it http://example.com/ ?
It seems that a character was stripped at the end.

Comment: I do not know; this is a mistake on my customer's end, where they enter some invalid data. Either way, I still want to be able to parse as much of it as possible, so return what the `PHP` implementation returns

Comment: If there is an error at user side, I think, it is better to put a try{}catch(){}. You can catch this exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException thus your program continue running very well.

Comment: Yes I can, and that's what I do. I just then return the original string without parsing it. But I still would like to parse the rest of the string, and contain the invalid portion. Again, like how PHP `urldecode` behaves